# Multiple wordpress category IF conditional tags

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, conditional-statements

Hi there I posted a question the other day about using conditional tags, which I managed to solve.

I've encountered another obstacle, I've managed to get one working by saying "If any posts are in the 'blogs' category echo '[BLOGS]'" but I'm trying to display posts in the blogs category and another. I read that to use multiple conditional tags to use the 'elseif' which I have but it doesn't seem to have done anything. Here is the code I'm using:

```
<h2>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php if (in_category ('blogs')) { ?>
            <?php _e('[BLOG]'); ?>
        <?php } elseif (in_category ('blogs', 'showstopper-spillings')) { ?>
            <?php _e('[BLOG] Showstopper Spillings:'); ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
  </h2>
```

Not sure if I'm missing anything, or even what I'm trying to do is possible. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

[in_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) only takes one category at a time.  Accordingly, you need to use compound statements to evaluate multiple categories.

```
<?php  
if (in_category ('blogs')) { 
        _e('[BLOG]');
} elseif (in_category ('other_category')) {
        _e('Other Category:');
} ?>
```

Substitute `other_category` with either the category id or the category name or category slug of your desired category.

Comment: Ok many thanks Christopher I'll do that, I'm guessing that would then work for three or four categories not only two like I listed?

Answer (score 1):

The PHP loks as ok as WP's PHP can look, so I think this is an issue of calling WP's functions. You have `in_category ('blogs', 'showstopper-spillings')` BUT it looks like the second parameter is meant to be the post id.

[Usage](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category)
`in_category( $category, $_post )`

$category
(mixed) (required) One or more categories specified by ID (integer), name or slug (string), or an array of these
Default: None

$_post
(mixed) (optional) The post (integer ID or object). Defaults to the current post in the Loop or the post in the main query.
Default: None

Assuming that "showstopper-spillings" is just another category the code should just be `` `in_category ('showstopper-spillings') ``

EDIT: and if you wanted to simply catch both at once you could do `if(in_category ('blogs') || in_category('showstopper-spillings'))` the two pipes "||" means "or"

Comment: I have done now, I've used the corrected code provided by Christopher. Should that allow me then to submit a post in both of these categories to get this result - [BLOGS] Showstopper Spillings: *title of post*?

Comment: It seems like Christopher's code is the one you want. If you use `if(in_category ('blogs') || in_category('showstopper-spillings'))` you'll get links to post in both categories, but the link will only read as "[BLOG]"

Comment: Yeah which is what I've just found out, so is there no way to display both then? If a post is in both categories, or does WP not work like that? Sorry for all the questions, totally new for me. It's all a learning curve at the end of the day :)

Comment: It's been a while since I dug into WP. I'm remembering now that there is some funky stuff happening with "the loop." ( https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop ) If you use this: `if(in_category ('blogs') || in_category('showstopper-spillings'))` you should get both, but you won't be able to display it under different categories.

Answer (score 1):

[in_category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/) and [is_category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/) do take an array of categories like this:

```
<?php if ( in_category(array('category-1', 'category-2')) ): ?>
  //do something
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( is_category(array('category-1', 'category-2')) ): ?>
  //do something
<?php endif; ?>
```

Note: the array ability was added in version 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this, by using php's double pipe for comparison and this will work fine..

Example:

```
<?php
 if( in_category('category-1') || in_category('category-2') ){
  //Do Something
 }
?>
```

Hope this helps others as I know this is an older post.